# If exception occurred unique lock will unlock the mutex

Tags: multithreading, exception, mutex, unique-lock

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include<mutex>
using namespace std;
mutex m;
int count;
void
func (const char *des)
{
  std::unique_lock < mutex > ul (m);
  cout << "in :" << des << endl;
  try
  {
    if (des == "T1")
      throw "T1";
  }
  catch ( ...)
  {
    cout << "catched" << endl;
  }
  this_thread::sleep_for (10 s);
  cout << "out of func" << endl;
}

int
main ()
{

  // Constructing two threads and run it. Does not block execution.
  thread t1 (func, "T1");
  thread t2 (func, "T2");

  cout << "main, t1 and t2 functions now execute concurrently...\n";

  // synchronize threads
  t1.join ();           // Makes the main thread wait until t1 finishes
  t2.join ();           // Makes the main thread wait until t2 finishes
}
```

Expecting Output: in T1
exception catched
T1 going to waiting state
in T2(because unique lock will unlock the mutex So T2 can start working with out T1 completing the task)
in :T2
out of func
out of func

current output: in T1
exception catched
T1 going to waiting state
out of func
in :T2
out of func

why tread 2 waiting for completion of thread 1 even exception occurred

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. That `std::unique_lock ul` object only ever gets destroyed at the end of `func` scope. When you throw the exception and catch it only objects within `try ... catch` block get destroyed, but `ul` is defined outside that block and, hence, it doesn't get destroyed.
2. `des == "T1"` compares string pointers, not string contents. It may or may not yield `true` when `des` points to string `T1`. You should compare C-style strings with [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp), e.g. `!std::strcmp(des, "T1")`.